# how to add clickable url to description in facebook app

Tags: facebook

How can I add a clickable url to the description in facebook app or if that is even possible.
I am posting to the wall, it all works fine except no clickable url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to programatically add clickable URLs by including html or similar.

Just include the URL in the copy of your description, and Facebook's code MAY detect this and make it clickable.